# Sum of the first four positive integer $ \ a \ $ such that $ \ a^{2019} \pmod{2019 }= 1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I've tried many times via  Euler's Theorem.

$   \varphi( 2019)  = 2\times 672 = 1344 $

$a^{\varphi(2019)} \equiv a^{1344}\equiv  1 \mod 2019$

then ,  $a^{2019} \equiv a^{675} \mod  2019$  , obviously $1$ is 1 of 4 for answers   and then how we can find another integer.

p.s. according to  [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%20%5E2019%20mod%202019%20%3D1) they've shown $3$ equation for integer solutions

I really appreciate for your help  .

Comment: Hint: $\large \ a^n\equiv 1\equiv a^k\,\Rightarrow a^{\gcd(n,k)}\equiv 1,\,$ so $\large \,a^3\equiv 1\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

As $2019=3\cdot673$

From the given condition

$a^{2019}\equiv1\pmod{673}$

But $2019\equiv3\pmod{\phi(673)}$

So, $a^3\equiv1\pmod{673}$

which has exactly three solutions

Trivially, $a\equiv1$

Else $a^2+a+1\equiv0\pmod{673}$

$\iff(2a+1)^2\equiv-3$ which is solvable as [Prove that $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod an odd prime $>3$ if and only if $p$ is of the form of $6n+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378911/prove-that-3-is-a-quadratic-residue-mod-an-odd-prime-3-if-and-only-if-p)

Similarly $$1\equiv a^{2019}\equiv a^1\pmod3$$ as $\phi(3)=2$

So using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html,  we should have exactly three solutions $\pmod{3\cdot673}$

Comment: it's torture with large prime to find $x^2 (mod 673) = - 3$ by hands  ,there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ distinct residue and I don't know what number between 1 to $\frac{p-1}{2}$  give $-3$ as residue $(mod 673)$ .

Comment: @ABCDEFGuser157844 We don't need to compute the nontrivial cube root. We only need to prove that it exists - which is easy by CRT (see the omment on my answer).

Comment: @ABC I just realized there is an ambiguity: do you seek the sum mod $2019$ or the sum as integers?

Comment: I don't know how to  describe in english , it's like  you finally got equation that
for  $a^{2019} \ mod(2019) = 1 \ $  we can represent $(a)$ by 

$a = 2019m + 1$ , $a = 2019m + 928$ , $a = 2019m +1090$  , which $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

and   the first four integer $(a)$ is $1,928,1090,2020,.......$ (arrange from minimum value)

Comment: and that's a problem that I cannot find that 3 equation to represent (a) because I don't know the way how to get them.

Comment: @ABC Even if we seek the sum as integers (vs. mod $2019)$ we still don't need to know the actual values of the 2nd & 3rd terms $\,a,\, a^2\,\bmod 2019,\,$ since I showed $\, S := 1+a+a^2\equiv 0\pmod{\!2019}$ and $\, a,a^2\le 2018\,$ when reduced mod $2019,\,$ thus  $\,1\le S < 2\cdot 2019\,$ so $\,S = 2019\,$ since $\,2019\mid S.\ \ $

Comment: I will do my best try to understand your solution ,although it's hard to understand for me because I'm still a  10th grade  high school student :) .

Comment: @ABC Do you know CRT = [Chinese Remainder Theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and [primitive roots?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).  Where does the problem come from, i.e. what was taught before it was posed?

Comment: I'm familiar with CRT but primitive roots am not, sorry no taught in the class is 3x harder for my school math subject. i just curious want to learning math out  of my class. searching many knowledge on internet by myself.

Comment: @ABC I updated my answer to show how to avoid using any knowledge of primitive roots.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ Since  $\ a^n\equiv 1\equiv a^k\,\Rightarrow a^{\gcd(n,k)}\equiv 1,\,$ we deduce $\,a^3\equiv 1$ so the sum of the first three roots is $\equiv 1+a+a^2\equiv 0,\,$ so the sum of the first four roots = fourth root = least root $(=1) + 2019$

**Update** $ $ Primitive roots are not known so we give a direct proof that if $p$ is prime and $3\mid p-1\,$ then $\,x^3-1\,$ has $\,3\,$ roots in the field $\,\Bbb Z_p = $ integers $\!\bmod p.\,$ Note  $\,3\mid p-1\,\Rightarrow\, x^3-1\mid x^{p-1}-1\,$ so $\,x^{p-1}-1 = (x^3-1)f(x)\,$ for a polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with integer coef's. [Since](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) a polynomial over a field has no more roots than its degree, if $\,x^3-1\,$ had less than $\,3\,$ roots then $\,(x^3-1)f(x)\,$ would have less than $\,p-1\,$ roots, contra it equals $\,x^{p-1}-1\,$ with $\,p-1\,$ roots, all $\,x\not\equiv 0,\,$ by little Fermat.

Comment: Further hint: verify via CRT, i.e. combine results mod $3$ and mod $\,p=673$. We get a cube root $\,a\not\equiv 1\pmod{\!3p}$ from a CRT solution of $\,a\equiv 1\pmod{\!3}\,$ and $\,a\equiv \zeta_3\pmod{\!p},\,$ where  $\,\zeta_3\,$ is a primitive cube root of $1$ mod $p,\,$ e.g. $\,\zeta_3 =  g^{(p-1)/3}\,$ for $g$ a primitive root mod $p.\,$  And $\,1+a+a^2\equiv 0\pmod{\!3p}$  since it holds mod $3$ and mod $p$.

Comment: Thank you for further hint.